# Shopify check how many orders a product has

Tags: shopify, liquid

Is possible to check how many orders/purchases a product has?

For example if a product has 3 orders/purchases, I want to hide it.

```
{% for product in collection.products %}
  // if ( product sells != 3 )
  <h2 class="title">{{ 'product.title' | t }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: No, on frontend with liquid it is not possible.

Comment: @Onkar i am new with Liquid. I have some experience with JS and PHP. What do you mean on frontend? Is there a backend Liquid? Is it not possible to get total sales of a product in Liquid?

Comment: Frontend means into the theme liquid file you can't get data, on the product edit screen it shows the product statistics about the sale, but unfortunately it doesn't available on the website frontend.

Answer (score -1):

1. In the product details, you can add a Metafield resource to it that is a number.
2. Edit that metafield so that it contains a 3 for example
3. in your theme, when you are examing the product details to decide whether to render the product or not, check the value of the metafield resource assigned to the product.
4. profit.

Comment: Is this above method autofill the meta field value from Shopify @David Lazar

Comment: In the front-end, values are available, so yes, auto-filled. If you refer to the setting of their values, that is up to the store owner. There are many ways to set and update values. I just answered this question, not all the questions that could be related.

Comment: My question regarding the sales number, is the numebers are filled manully or fetch from Shopify actual sales, that's it

Comment: Your question is confusing to answer.

Comment: This is not a good solution. I need a way to see how many orders an item has. To my understanding a custom metafield will hold a value that I add to it like 3. Orders are dynamic. The number of orders change. How would a metafield return how many orders a product has? Do i have to manually enter the orders for each product in the metafield as products are sold?? If so, this is a poor solution.

Comment: I am asking the same, meta field value I think remain static untill you update it manully?

Comment: Now you are asking a different question. How to calculate and update values from orders (# of products sold). That is an entire subject on itself. My solution is perfectly fine. You have a lot of work in front of you!